# QTcpSocket - Connection Refused until Port Changed

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket

I apologize, I was not sure how to deliver a concise title for this issue.

**Background:** I am using QTcpSocket to connect to a PLC Simulator application. Previously I was using [PLCQTLIB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plcqtlib/) to connect to the simulator and everything was working fine. The library did not offer enough functionality for my project so I have created my own library for interfacing Qt with the [libnodave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net/) library.

The simulator runs on IP Address 192.168.32.1 and Port 102

**Current Issue:** I enter the IP (192.168.32.1) and Port (102) and press connect. I receive:

> TCP Error =  QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError
>
> TCP Error =  QAbstractSocket::SocketTimeoutError

If I change the port to 80 and press connect, the connection is successful. However the connection to the PLC Simulator will fail because it is not listening on Port 80.

Now that a *successful connection* has been established to 192.168.32.1 and the *current state* of the connection is *disconnected*, I can enter the correct port 102 and connect successfully.

**Question:** Why does the TCP Socket not establish a connection to Port 102 until after a connection has been previously opened on Port 80? No firewalls exist and all communication is occurring on the local machine.

*Declared in Header:*

`QTcpSocket *tcp;`

*Source File:*

```
PLCLibNoDave::PLCLibNoDave()
{
    tcp = new QTcpSocket();

    connect(tcp, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),
            this, SLOT(tcpStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
    connect(tcp, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(tcpErrorHandler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(tcp, SIGNAL(hostFound()), this, SLOT(tcpHostFound()));
    connect(tcp, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(tcpConnected()));
    connect(tcp, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(tcpDisconnected()));
}

void PLCLibNoDave::connectTCP(int port, QString ip)
{
    tcp->connectToHost(ip,port);
    if(!tcp->waitForConnected(3000)){
        tcp->disconnectFromHost();
        return;
    }
    tcpHandle = tcp->socketDescriptor();
    if(tcpHandle == -1){
        tcp->disconnectFromHost();
        qDebug() << "Invalid Socket Descriptor on Connect";
        return;
    }

    return;
}

void PLCLibNoDave::disconnectTCP()
{
    tcp->disconnectFromHost();

    if(tcp->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState ||
            tcp->waitForDisconnected(1000)){
        tcpError = tcp->error();
    }
    else{
        tcpError = tcp->error();
        qDebug() << "Disconnect Failed: " << tcp->errorString();
    }
    return;

}
```

Comment: Just for some clarification, you say "No firewalls exist and all communication is occurring on the local machine.". Does that mean that both your application and your simulator are running on the same PC? How does your simulator work? You said it is listening on port 102, this means it is connected to port 102 and probably another app cannot connect (assuming its not a shared connection).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes both my application and the PLC Simulator are running on the same PC. 

The simulator opens with a default IP address of 192.168.0.1. There is an option to declare a *Network IP Address*. Here I choose 192.168.32.1. The simulator states that it is running on port 102. To connect to the simulator you enter the IP Address 192.168.32.1 and Port 102.

Did that provide any clarification?

Comment: Note - I have not had any issues connecting directly to 192.168.32.1 and Port 102 in the past.

Comment: hmm... I have the feeling that your sim is connected (connected = listening) on port 102. Your app is then also trying to connect (listen) on port 102. I believe you have to either use a shared connection (I never used that before) or you have to both listen to different ports. Why are trying to listen on the same port? If its a case of Sim listens on port 102 and app sends to that port, then you don't actually need to connect to be able to send. The connection is purely for listening on. I.e. you can connect on port 80 and still send to port 102.

Comment: Oh, wait... I might be talking about QUdpSocket!, which is slightly different, sorry. But still I think you have some conflict with your simulator. To test that you can disable your simulator and then try to connect to 102. It might be a port mode issue (readonly / read/write) etc...

Comment: Unfortunately I need to both send to and receive from the simulator. If I close the simulator I am unable to connect to port 102 at all. Opening the simulator again, I can reestablish a connection. The issue is only when the Qt Application first starts. After establishing connection to port 80, I can disconnect and then establish connection with port 102. This is very strange behavior, for which I cannot offer myself an explanation.

Comment: I would be tempted to make your own Qt-Tcp server (a real simple one) to help diagnose. There is somthing odd about this setup, I can't quite think if its the sim or not. Do you run the Sim seperatley each time, or is it always running?